# Property does not exist on type 'typeof CommonStore'. mobx-react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I am new to TypeScript and I try to call an action from another class and I get such an error, maybe it’s not possible to use functions through import but only through `@inject`? What could be the problem I do not understand

### P.S. established `@types`:

```js
"@types/react": "^16.8.22",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.8.4",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.4",
```

```js
import {
  observable,
  action,
  autorun,
  set,
  toJS,
  extendObservable
} from "mobx";
import commonStore from "./common";

export default class Authentication {
  @action login = async() => {
    this.inProgress = true;
    this.errors = undefined;
    try {
      const token = await requestApi({
        method: "post",
        url: `/auth/login`,
        data: {
          login: this.username,
          pass: this.password
        }
      });

      commonStore.setToken(token); // Property 'setToken' does not exist on type 'typeof CommonStore'
    } catch (error) {
      axiosErrorHandler(error);
    }
  }
}
```

**CommonStore**

```js
export default class CommonStore {
  @observable token = window.localStorage.getItem("jwt");
  constructor() {
    reaction(
      () => this.token,
      token => {
        if (token) {
          localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
        } else {
          localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
        }
      }
    );
  }

  @action setToken(token: string) {
    this.token = token;
  }
}
```

**index.ts store**

```js
import Authentication from "./models/authentication";
import Common from "./models/common";

class ObservableListStore {
  @observable authentication = new Authentication();
  @observable common = new Common();
}

export const store = new ObservableListStore();
```

Comment: How the _ common.ts_ looks?

Comment: I described below (Common Store)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exported a class (`CommonStore`) but you're trying use it like an object that already created.

You need to create the instance and then you could use it.

```js
import commonStore from "./common";

const commonStoreInstance = new commonStore();

commonStoreInstance.setToken('token');
```

But probably you want the same instance wherever you `import` the `commonStore`. If so, you need to create the instance inside the module and export that.

Like this:

```js
class CommonStore {
  @observable token = window.localStorage.getItem("jwt");
  constructor() {
    reaction(
      () => this.token,
      token => {
        if (token) {
          localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
        } else {
          localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
        }
      }
    );
  }

  @action setToken(token: string) {
    this.token = token;
  }
}

export const commonStore = new CommonStore();
```

Then

```js
import commonStore from "./common";

commonStore.setToken('token');
```

https://k94n.com/es6-modules-single-instance-pattern

Comment: I have a file that has all of my instances , will it break anything? I updated code

Comment: I just want to understand how to do it correctly, maybe I’m not properly structuring my stores? I used your first advice and everything works, but it looks like a crutch, I would like a more elegant solution.

Comment: I'm not sure why it looks that way to you but look at those projects: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-game-kit/blob/master/demo/game/stores/game-store.js#L23, https://github.com/fcsonline/react-transmission/blob/master/src/stores/index.js#L20-L22 and so on.